# How to change the background color in a div in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change the background color in the selected div using j Query?

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(':radio').bind('change',function(){
        var th = $(this);
        id = th.attr('id'); 
        var divid = 'format-id_'+id;

        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $(':radio[id="'  + id + '"]').not($(this)).attr('disabled',true); 
            $(divid).attr('id').css('background-color', '#cccccc');
        } else {
            $(':radio[id="'  + id + '"]').not($(this)).attr('disabled',false);  
            $(divid).attr('id').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: $(divid).css('background-color', '#cccccc'); it should be like this

Comment: `$(divid).css('background-color', '#cccccc');` try this.

Comment: Open your console for debugging purpose

Comment: Answer should fix your issue, and by the way if you do `var th = $(this);` then use `th` again afterwards instead of `$(this)`, it will reduce the amount of function calls by quite a bit.

Comment: you have a trivial error in the code. You should check errors on console or at least have a look at what you're doing. Even this selector is no sense: $(':radio[id="'  + id + '"]').not($(this)), id should be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(divid).attr('id')` should be `$('#' + divid)`, to select by that ID.

```
$('#' + divid).css('background-color', '#cccccc');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(':radio').bind('change',function(){
        var th = $(this);
        id = th.attr('id'); 
        var divid = 'format-id_'+id;

        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $(':radio[id="'  + id + '"]').not($(this)).attr('disabled',true); 
            $('#' + divid).css('background-color', '#cccccc');
        } else {
            $(':radio[id="'  + id + '"]').not($(this)).attr('disabled',false);  
            $('#' + divid).css('background-color', '#ffffff');
        }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're code,  can be translated to:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(':radio').bind('change',function(){
        var th = $(this);
        var id = th.attr('id'); 
        var divid = '#format-id_'+id;

        //The following does not have much sense, id should be unique in DOM
        //so here you getting the same element excluding it so nothing happens
        //$(':radio[id="'  + id + '"]').not($(this)).attr('disabled',true);

        if( th.is(':checked') ){
            $(divid).css('background-color', '#cccccc');
        } else {
            $(divid).css('background-color', '#ffffff');
        }
     });
});
```